# Error: "No value given for one or more required parameters" on UPDATE query from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

I receive the error

> No value given for one or more required parameters

when I try to execute the following code

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim t2 = TextBox2.Text

    Dim dbcmd As OleDbCommand
    dbcmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE login1 SET height ='" + TextBox2.Text + "' WHERE username =" + str, dbcon) //This is the part where the error is ....
    dbcon.Open()
    dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    dbcon.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

I've tried making changes in this statement like using different methods with parameters...but all the code shows the same error.

Comment: I'll bet the problem is that the input you're using has a parameter placeholder character in it.  Thus, the problem you're facing is that your code is ***wide open*** to SQL injection.  You need to use SQL parameters to treat user input as *data* instead of treating is as ***executable code***.

Answer (score 2):

Using a parameterized query is definitely the way to go, but using *named* parameters should be discouraged in this context because `OleDbCommand` objects **ignore** the parameter names when the `CommandType` is `Text`. They only rely on the *order* in which the parameters appear in the `CommandText` (ref: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Therefore, the preferred approach would be

```vb
Using dbcmd As New OleDbCommand(
            "UPDATE login1 SET height=? WHERE username=?",
            dbcon)
    dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox2.Text)  ' height
    dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", str)  ' username
    dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't supply the user name ***properly*** at the end of the query. But that's not the only problem here. Let me edit the code a bit:

```
Using dbcon As New OleDbConnection(cString)
    dbcon.Open()

    Using dbcmd As New OleDbCommand(
        "UPDATE login1 SET height = @height WHERE username = @username",
        dbcon)
        dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@height", TextBox2.Text)
        dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", str)

        dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

**NOTE:** the `using` statement to ensure the objects are *disposed* property and also, **do not share connections.** When you need a connection, build it, open it, use it, and dispose it.

Comment: While not exactly wrong, using *named* parameters is discouraged in this context because ACE.OLEDB actually ignores the names and only relies on the *order* of the parameters. `SET height=? WHERE username=?` is preferred.

Comment: @GordThompson, very interesting point and a great addition - thanks a lot!